# How to style a table in R correctly

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very very new to R and need to make a table. I got following set up of data:

```
    reaktionszeit           arbeitszeit             wissen     
1   Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  
2   Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  
3   Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  
4   Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  
5   Sehr zufriedenstellend            Keine Angabe  Sehr zufriedenstellend  
6   Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  
7        Zufriedenstellend       Zufriedenstellend Nicht zufriedenstellend 
8   Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend  Sehr zufriedenstellend
```

What I basically want is that the categories are displayed on the X-Axis and the different gradings on the Y-Axis, therefore am I getting which categories received which rating how often. This must be a super easy task but I am not able to achieve it.

I played around with the `table()` function but came to no conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably with a package like `dplyr` it can be done easily. Using base system you can proceed as follow:

For table

```
  df = data.frame(
   'reaktionszeit' = c('Sehr zufriedenstellend', 'Sehr zufriedenstellend', 'Zufriedenstellend'),
   'arbeitszeit' = c('Sehr zufriedenstellend', 'Sehr zufriedenstellend', 'Sehr zufriedenstellend'),
   'wissen' = c('Sehr zufriedenstellend', 'Nicht zufriedenstellend', 'Nicht zufriedenstellend') )
```

I would apply table to each column

```
 l_tab = apply(df, 2, table)
```

Then, I would get the names available in the data.frame

```
 vals = unique(as.character(unlist(df)))
```

I would merge the results in a new table

```
tab = do.call(`rbind`, lapply(l_tab, function(x) x[vals]))
```

And finally, I'll put the names to `tab`

```
colnames(tab) = vals
tab
```

But certainly, if you want to try `dplyr` package, you'll find more elegant ways.

Comment: Hi, I got it running without using the dplyr package, nevertheless do I have NAs now in 3 rows...d you know how to handle them?

Comment: Yes, you can replace the `NA`'s by 0's with `tab[is.na(tab)] = 0`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry I am really new. During which step of the above mentioned would I have to perform this in order to get no NA values after calling the final "tab"?

Comment: I would perform the replacement anytime after `tab = do.call(`rbind`, lapply(l_tab, function(x) x[vals]))` line. Instruction `tab` is there just to print the final result.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I have to run this statement during a statement which you have mentioned previously. It's all working now perfectly!